# which name is acceptable for class extends abstract class?

Tags: java

I have three classes:

1. `ZookeeperAccess` is interface
2. `AbstractZookeeperAccess` implements ZookeeperAccess
3. is a class that extends `AbstractZookeeperAccess`

What would a good name for the 3rd class be?

I use `ZookeeperAccessImpl`, but I suppose this isn't the best name, it hint only implements the  `ZookeeperAccess`, but not extends `AbstractZookeeperAccess`.

ps: the `ZookeeperAccessImpl` is the only class extends `AbstractZookeeperAccess` now.

I use abstract class to implement some code for interface, and provide some code to be abstact for ZookeeperAccessImpl to extends.

I update the question again. Thanks

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag it as such if so.

Comment: If it is the only class that extends `AbstractZookeeperAccess`, why do you need `AbstractZookeeperAccess`?

Comment: It highly depends on what the implementation actually does, can you give some more explanation about the functions these classes offer?

Comment: Also: I think it is the other way around, how is the `AbstractZooKeeperAccess` differs from its super `ZooKeeperAccess`? Maybe `AbstractZooKeeperAccess` should be renamed?

Comment: I use abstract class to implement some code for interface, and provide some code to be abstact for ZookeeperAccessImpl to extends.

Comment: You should update your question : ZookeeperAccess is an interface not a class.

Comment: I have update question, the former question contains two questions so that it cause puzzle. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have `AbstractZookeeperAccess` implies there is more than one subclass to implement each type of `ZookeeperAccess`, so prefix the subclass names with the type.

For example, given:

```
interface ZookeeperAccess
AbstractZookeeperAccess implements ZookeeperAccess
```

You might have

```
FullTimeZookeeperAccess extends AbstractZookeeperAccess
PartTimeZookeeperAccess extends AbstractZookeeperAccess
TemporaryZookeeperAccess extends AbstractZookeeperAccess
```

Answer (score 1):

The name should explains what the implementation does. This implementation could be done by extending an abstract class,  delegating to another...

For example in `java.util`, `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` implentents `List` and ... extends `AbstractList`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that the class name needs to imply that it extends the abstract class ?

For the appropriate classnames, i usually use a *prefix* that shows the *implementation specific* of each classes.

For example, an interface of **EmployeeDao**,

with an abstract class of **BaseEmployeeDao**

and the implementations' names could be something like these :

- PostgresEmployeeDao
- OracleEmployeeDao
- MongodbEmployeeDao
- SerializationEmployeeDao

Answer (score 1):

The class name should clearly state the what the class does, so when you need an `I`-prefix (for interfaces) or an `Impl`-suffix, you are probably doing something wrong.

An interface name should state how it can be used (eg. `Map`). If the main purpose of a class is implementing an interface, it should say something **specific** about the implementation (eg. `HashMap`). In this case, all variables and members should be declared as the interface-type, and the class is only used for instantiation (unless the concrete implementation is important, which it shouldn't)

`Impl` suggests that there is only one meaningful implementation. If so, why do you need an interface at all? (A possible answer might be: I want to hide the implementation from the user of the API, <s>Sun</s> Oracle does that a lot.)

If you just want to provide a default implementation (because you expect the API-user to come up with more efficient solutions), what about `Default`, `Simple`, or `Direct`-`ZookeeperAccess`?

For abstract classes, I prefer using the `Base`-suffix (eg. `ZookeeperAccessBase`), it works better with the autocompletion of most IDEs.